# Missing delimiter (.inserted)

Tags: missing

I am new to latex and am trying to create the following in latex:
[image]

It looks similar to what I want when I use this:

```
$\scriptsize 0_{{\big T}{\small 1}} =
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
! Missing delimiter (. inserted).
<to be read again>
T
l.10 $\scriptsize 0_{{\big T
}{\small 1}} =
I was expecting to see something like `(' or `\{' or
`\}' here. If you typed, e.g., `{' instead of `\{', you
should probably delete the `{' by typing `1' now, so that
braces don't get unbalanced. Otherwise just proceed.
Acceptable delimiters are characters whose \delcode is
nonnegative, or you can use `\delimiter <delimiter code>'.
```

I am not sure how to fix the error and am hoping someone on here can help me :)

Comment: `\big` does not change the font size in math mode but is used for delimiters like `{` or `)`...

Comment: Does `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$ ^0T_1 = $
\end{document}` give the desired output? https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UhO8.png

Comment: `\big` must be followed by a delimiter; it doesn't change the size of arbitrary symbols. What do you need, precisely?

Comment: in addition to `\Big` being an error, the  text size changes such as `\scriptsize` and `\small` should not be used in math mode (they give a warning and do not work as you might expect)

Comment: @leandriis Yes, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to change the font size of the elements, use super- and subscripts as shown in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document} 
$ ^0T_1 = $ 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The drawing in the question looks more like a sans serif letter than an ordinary italic variable.  Maybe `{\top}` would work, although I think a larger size would be better.  (The braces enclosing `\top` are necessary to disable the usual spacing; this should be an "ordinary" character, although probably a "large operator" without limits could work.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: It is indeed true that the code does not exactly reproduce the sketch in the question. However, [the OP seemed to be satisfied](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/494333/missing-delimiter-inserted/494360?noredirect=1#comment1248012_494333) iwth this solution that I already included in [a previous comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/494333/missing-delimiter-inserted/494360?noredirect=1#comment1247991_494333).